# docker-compose is using a cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I can't get docker-compose up to work.  If I docker-compose --verbose up I get the following...

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['-c', '["bin/rails", "s", "-b" "0.0.0.0]'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/bin/sh', '-c', '["bin/rails", "s", "-b" "0.0.0.0]'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
                    'RUBY_MAJOR=2.7',
```

A one point in the past my command was missing the double quotes after "0.0.0.0".  However, I've updated my Dockerfile such that line now says

```
CMD ["bin/rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

How do I get docker to use my Dockerfile?  When I run docker-compose up I get

```
web_1  | /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: You can use `--build` flag to rebuild some service. Let's say you have defined service in compose file and named it `backend-srvc`. You can use `docker-compose build backend-srvc` to rebuild it and then `docker-compose up` to run all of them. Or you can use `docker-compose up --build backend-srvc` which will rebuild `backend-srvc` and start all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to

`docker system prune -a`

and then docker-compose up worked.  There goes an afternoon I'll never get back.